# Postgres, return default row if id doesn't exist in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm selecting rows from a table where the id is in an array.  This works, but I also want to return default values for rows that do not exist in the table.

I currently have

```
  SELECT
    id,
    column1
  FROM
    table_name
  WHERE
    id = ANY(ids_array_variable)
```

but, if some of the ids in the array do not exist in the table, then my result is short a few rows.  I need it to still return a default record of {id, default_value} so that the result always has the same number of entries as the ids_array_variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a left join:

```
select a.id, 
       coalesce(t.column1, 'some default') as column1
from unnest(ids_array_variable) as a(id)
  left join table_name t on t.id = a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

if table serviceconfig have n’t key - ‘*my_key*’ - use default value

thank [@a-horse-with-no-name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(KV.value, def.val) as value
FROM (
    select def.val from unnest(ARRAY ['default']) as def(val)) as def
LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM serviceconfig
      WHERE key = 'my_key') KV on true;
```